# Why can't you call functions on a pointer object?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, operator-precedence

Edit: sorry about the stupid title; by "pointer object" I think I mean dereferenced object pointer (if that's any clarification).

I'm new to C++, and I've been trying to get used to its idiosyncrasies (coming from Java).

I know it's not usually necessary, but I wanted to try passing an object by its pointer. It works, of course, but I was expecting this to work too:

```
void test(Dog * d) {
*d.bark();
}
```

And it doesn't. Why is this? I found out that I can do the following:

```
void test(Dog * d) {
Dog dawg = *d;
dawg.bark();
}
```

and it works flawlessly. It seems so redundant to me.

Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Great answers. Thanks everyone. I had no idea you could separate something like *dog with parenthesis.

Comment: Edited my answer, Alex; hope it clarifies the reason you can do things like that :)

Comment: @Alex Reidy: Slightly unrelated..but note that `Dog dawg = *d;` will create a *copy* of `d` object passed. So `bark` will be called on the copied object and not on the `d`.

Comment: @AlexReidy Also, please upvote and/or accept answers which helped you :)

Comment: @AlexReidy Actually I upvoted 3 other answers on this question because they were right, too.  And your stats made me think you were new to the site, so I was trying to explain how things worked in case you weren't aware.  Apologies if it came across the wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `->` operator on pointers.  The `.` operator is for non-pointer objects.

In your first code snippet, try `d->bark();`.  Should work fine!

---

EDIT:  Other answers suggest `(*d).bark();`.  That will work as well; the `(*d)` dereferences the pointer (ie. turns it into a normal object) which is why the `.` operator works.  To use the original pointer, simply `d`, you must use the `->` operator as I described.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great explanation of both methods! I always thought order of operations and parenthesis were only for mathematical operations.

Comment: @AlexReidy Thank you! :) And nope, parentheses just mean "do this first".

Comment: @WendiKidd: *"You have to use the -> operator on pointers."*. One can apply `->` on non-pointer object of type `T` also, if `T` has overloaded `operator->` .

Answer (score 9):

Imo . has precedence over dereference * , thus:

```
(*d).bark();
```

or, for pointers, as stated in other replies - use `->`

```
d->bark();
```

be sure to check for null :)

Comment: IMO? Your opinion has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ah, right. Pardon my english, I meant AFAIK :)  8 years since C++ days

Answer (score 7):

Just to clarify the situation, you can use *either* `(*pointer).member()`, or `pointer->member()` -- `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`.

That, of course, is assuming you're dealing with "real" (built-in) pointers. It's *possible* to overload `operator->` to do something different. Overloads of `operator->` are somewhat restricted though, which generally prevents people from doing *too* strange of things with them. The one thing you might run into (e.g., with *old* implementations of some iterators) is simply failing to support `operator->` at all, so trying to use it will result in a compile error. Though such implementations are (mostly?) long gone, you might still see some (typically older) code that uses `(*iterator).whatever` instead of `->` because of this.

Answer (score 6):

Its all in the parentheses:

```
(*d).bark();
```

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is missing one point to answer: **Operator Precedence**.

The precedence of `operator.` is higher than that of (unary) pointer indirection (`*`) opeartor. That's why brackets are needed. It's just like putting parenthesis around + to get correct average:

```
int nAverage = (n1+n2) / 2;
```

For pointer indirection case, you are lukcy that compiler is giving you error!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `->` operator when using pointers, i.e. code should be `d->bark();`.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot what that was for.